# How to get the active TabBarButton in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to underline the text of the active `tabBarButton` but it seems that it doesn't provide the `focused prop`. How can i do that ?

```js
<Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeNavigator}
          options={() => ({
            title: 'Home',
            tabBarButton: (props) => (
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback {...props} >
                <View style={{flex:2, alignItems: 'center'}}>
                  <Image source={LOGO} resizeMode="contain" style={[styles.imgSize, props.focused && { opacity:1 }]} />
                  <Text style={[styles.label, props.focused && { opacity:1, textDecorationLine: 'underline' }]}>HOME</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            ),
          })}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap you `Tab.Screen` inside a `Tab.Navigator`, because the `focused` prop is inside the `navigator` ([here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/))

```js
<Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName={"Home"}

      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            let imageStyle
            let textStyle

            if (route.name === "Home") {
              imageStyle = focused ? styles.activeImageStyle : styles.inactiveImageStyle
              textStyle = focused ? styles.activeTextStyle : styles.inactiveTextStyle
            }
            if (route.name === "OtherScreen") {
              imageStyle = focused ? styles.activeImageStyle : styles.inactiveImageStyle
              textStyle = focused ? styles.activeTextStyle : styles.inactiveTextStyle
            }

            return <TabBarIcon imageStyle={imageStyle} textStyle={textStyle}/>
          },
          headerStatusBarHeight: 0,

        }
      )}
      tabBarOptions={{
        showLabel: false,
        style: styles.tabBarStyle,
        keyboardHidesTabBar: true,
        safeAreaInsets: { bottom: 0 }
      }}
    >
    
  <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeNavigator}
      
  />    
   <Tab.Screen
          name="OtherScreen"
          component={OtherNavigator}
      
  /> 

</Tab.Navigator>


// And your styles could be

const styles = export default StyleSheet.create({
 activeImageStyle: {...},
 inactiveImageStyle: {...},
 activeTextStyle: {...},
 inactiveTextStyle: {...}
 
 })

// Where you can declare you TabBarIcon in another file as being this 

 <TouchableWithoutFeedback {...props} >
                <View style={{flex:2, alignItems: 'center'}}>
                  <Image source={LOGO} resizeMode="contain" style={[styles.imgSize, props.imageStyle ]} />
                  <Text style={[styles.label, props.textStyle]}>HOME</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```